# Package libdtrace-ctf is unavailable in Oracle Linux 8?

Tags: yum, oracle-linux

I'm trying to install libdtrace-ctf in Oracle Linux 8, so I started a container with `docker run -it oraclelinux:8 /bin/bash`, and executed the following commands

```
[root@4730e14b58e1 /]# yum clean all
16 files removed
[root@4730e14b58e1 /]# yum search libdtrace
Oracle Linux 8 BaseOS Latest (x86_64)                                                                                                           2.2 MB/s |  26 MB     00:11
Oracle Linux 8 Application Stream (x86_64)                                                                                                      2.2 MB/s |  22 MB     00:10
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:04 ago on Thu Oct 22 02:32:24 2020.
No matches found.
```

It's unavailable, but I can find the package here http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/developer/UEKR6/x86_64/index.html

So what was wrong?

Comment: That is the repo for development preview packages. Do you have that repo? Add the output of `yum repolist` to you question.

Comment: @NasirRiley No I didn't add that repo, how can I do that?

Comment: You have 46K reputation and you don't know how to add a repo?